# Espresso won't wait for mock response with custom Interceptor

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit, android-espresso

I'm writing an UI test which includes Espresso and Retrofit. My espresso won't wait for my fake API to draw all the data before clicking the next button.

I created a custom class like this to make mock response:

```
public class FakeInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private final static String TAG = FakeInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();

// FAKE JSON RESPONSES.
private final static String PROFILE__USER_RECOMMENDS = JsonDataSource.jsonUserRecommends;
private final static String PROFILE__USER = JsonDataSource.jsonUser;


@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response response;
    String responseString = "";
    // Get Requested link.
    String requestedPath = chain.request().url().encodedPath();

    if (requestedPath.equalsIgnoreCase("api/users/profile/recommendsTab")) {
        responseString = PROFILE__USER_RECOMMENDS;
    } else if (requestedPath.equalsIgnoreCase("api/users/me")) {
        responseString = PROFILE__USER;
    }

    response = new Response.Builder()
            .code(200)
            .message(responseString)
            .request(chain.request())
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
            .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), responseString.getBytes()))
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .build();

    return response;
}
}
```

However, the problem occurs when I use retrofit instance with that `FakeInterceptor` with espresso.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new FakeInterceptor()).build();
```

and build the retrofit instance

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(JsonUtils.getInstance().getGson()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Constants.END_POINT)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

When I use the `perform(click())` for `onView` like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button_1)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.button_2)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.button_3)).perform(click());
```

(Keep in mind that each button changes the fragment and each fragment loads the API to show data). The button is clicked continuously, the data has no chance to be shown.

But if I don't use `addInterceptor(new FakeInterceptor())` and let retrofit call real API, each click waits for the API, allows data to be shown before the next button is clicked.

This is how I call the mock API

```
 @Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

UserRepository mockUserRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    mockUserRepository = Injection.provideUserRepository(appContext); // This mockUserRepository will use the retrofit instance with `FakeInterceptor`

    Mockito.when(userRepository.getUserInfo()).thenReturn(mockUserRepository.getUserInfo()); //Use the mock repository if the real user repository is called.
}
```

I don't know if I miss something in the `FakeInterceptor` that would make espresso thinks that I'm using the real API not the mocked one.

Any help on how to make the espresso waits for the API is appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

I put a break point at `responseString = PROFILE__USER` which is supposed to be triggered if `mockUserRepository.getUserInfo()` is called but it never got called. So as the the whole method `intercept(Chain chain)` looks like this FakeInterceptor has problems